# How is a thread waiting for mutex put back to running?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex, wait

The context is like this:

- a thread tries to lock a already locked mutex
- the thread is put to sleep/blocking
- after some while, the mutex is unlocked

Q1) What will happen then ?

will the thread be immediately put back to running?  Or kernel will still wait the running thread consume its time slice and schedule the waiting thread normally?

Q2) What if the mutex is not unlocked forever? How does the kernel determine to keep the thread waiting?

Comment: Smell like homework.... or exam

Comment: If the mutex is never unlocked you have a deadlock in your program, and as far as the kernel is concerned, it's your problem

Comment: @LPs NO - it's an interview question.. I think the kernel will schedule the waiting thread normally and will check the mutex status again before put it back to running. But not sure.

Comment: @StoryTeller I am fully aware of this, this is not the question. The question is about the implementation details of the dead lock / forever waiting .

Comment: @guardian Your thoughts on what may happen honestly should be in your question, not just down here in comment malaise. It would actually lend to the meat of the post, and show effort and thought, rather than just fishing for answers. Just a suggestion.

Comment: I guess it is implementation defined?

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for your advice, but if you read more carefully my question, I have already expressed my thought there.

Answer (score 2):

> Will the thread be immediately put back to running? Or kernel will still wait the running thread consume its time slice and schedule the waiting thread normally?

Typically the thread is now ready-to-run. On most systems, if there's an available core, it will begin running immediately. If not, then it will be considered the next time the scheduler is invoked on any core.

> What if the mutex is not unlocked forever? How does the kernel determine to keep the thread waiting?

Typically, the first thing the thread does when it wakes up is try to lock the mutex. If it fails, it blocks again. Some implementations assign the mutex to a particular thread before they make it ready-to-run, in which case the thread wakes up with the mutex.

Implementations vary and may do anything that conforms to the requirements.

Comment: How is kernel magically set the waiting thread as ready-to-run ?  Is there some kind of waiting thread list of the mutex the kernel can use to flip the status ?

Comment: @FaceBro - Obviously the OS will have to keep track of all the threads all the time, so it just knows. C and Posix doesn't say how it should do that, but having some lists of thread-ids might be a good way.

Comment: @FaceBro I'm most familiar with Linux's implementation, and that is precisely how it works.